# She made Jerry out to be famous. ['raising to object' construction?]

Tags: control, raising

> (1) *She made Jerry out to be famous*.

In linguistics literature such as [here](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=xL33CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT685&lpg=PT685&dq=%22made%20Jerry%20out%20to%20be%20famous%22%20raising&source=bl&ots=2yv2BH-eFl&sig=ACfU3U2hFGVSR65ANAjHI2084-4s6DtAeA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY8q-C1pzhAhXtyosBHZH5DHUQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22made%20Jerry%20out%20to%20be%20famous%22%20raising&f=false), this sentence was used as an example of 'raising to object' where 'Jerry' raises to object of the matrix clause while semantically it is subject of the VP (*to be famous*).

But *to be* is not really necessary part of the expression 'make someone/something out', for you can omit it as in:

> (2) *Jerry was not so famous as she made him out*.

Then, I wonder why (1) should be analyzed as a 'raising to object' construction, not as a 'object control' construction where *Jerry* identifies the implicit subject of the infinitival clause (*to be famous*).

If the verb *made* in (1) has to be analyzed as a 'raising to object' verb, should the same verb in (2) or (3) be analyzed as a 'raising to object' verb?

> (3) *She made Jerry out as famous*.

Comment: (2) and (3) are not grammatical for me. (2) would have to be *Jerry was not as famous as she made out*. In that sentence *as ... as she made out* is just quantifying the *famous* - no need for raising. (3) would have to be (1). BTW there was some discussion of raising in relation to prepositions some while back - Google McCloskey 1984, Raising, Subcategorization and Selection in Modern Irish and Joseph, IS RAISING TO PREPOSITIONAL OBJECT A NATURAL
LANGUAGE GRAMMATICAL CONSTRUCTION?

Comment: @Minty I believe (2) and (3) are grammatical, if not as idiomatic as (1). I think _Jerry was not as famous as she made out._ is of questionable acceptability.

Comment: I don't find your (2) to be acceptable (without "to be" added at the end).  But even if it is grammatical, how does it show that (1) is an object control construction?  I don't understand the logic of your argument.

Comment: (1) Many people say _as_ instead of _so_ in this construction. This appears to be irrelevant here. (2) is grammatical for me only with _to be_ at the end. (3) is ungrammatical; _make out as_ in this construction refers to visual acuity or its metaphoric projection (_I can just make it out as a stop sign_).

Comment: @GregLee The logic is, if in (2) _to be_ were the subordinate clause from which _him_ raises to object of _made_, you can't omit _to be_. For example, you can't omit _to be_ here: _Jerry was not so famous as she believed him to be._

Comment: Why can't you omit "to be" when it is the predicate of the raised subject?  How does that follow in any theory?

Comment: @GregLee In (2), _to be_ is an elided version of _to be famous_, the elision being attributable to comparison. Thus, being able to elide _to be_ in (2) means that the VP (_to be famous_) is not complement of the verb _made_ in the first place. This in turn means that the verb _made_ is not a raising verb, unlike the verb _believed_ in _Jerry was not so famous as she believed him to be_.

Comment: @jlawler Counterexamples are found in Merriam-Webster Dictionary: _Then suppose that something turns up suggesting that the story might not be quite true, or not quite so bad as it was made out._ https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20out#examples

Comment: @JK2 I think that's expletive *it*, in which case it's not a counter-example. I still haven't grasped what you've got against raising (as distinct from movement) or what the alternative explanation of the central cases would be.

Comment: @Minty The _it_ refers back to _the story_. You can't use the expletive _it_ in a comparative clause without stating the extraposed subject. Without stating the extraposed subject, you should elide the expletive _it_.

Comment: @Minty And here's another example from Longman Dictionary: _The situation was never as bad as the media made out._ https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/make-out

Comment: @JK2 well it would certainly sound better elided - let's see what the more experienced/learned folks say. If you're right though, it just means the two things are incompatible - it doesn't tell us which one is wrong.

Comment: @JK2 but there's no *it* at all in that - it's just the same as my (2) above.

Comment: @Minty Here are other examples from Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary: _Don't make them out as worse than they are._ // _He's not as bad as he's made out (to be)._ = _He's not as bad as people make him out (to be)._ http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/make

Comment: @JK OK well if MW really mean that the *he's / him* can stay in if the *to be* is dropped, then the second and third of those are clearly counterexamples. They sound wrong to me, but I'm not the arbiter of what's grammatical and ungrammatical, and there seems to be more disagreement around that than I would have expected. Some of Postal's supposedly correct examples strike me as wrong, for example, whereas some of his starred examples strike me as fine.

Comment: I think you should look at "She made him famous", and ask yourself if every object complement isn't also a form of raising to object ("She made him [[to] be] famous"), ... and then extend to phrasal verbs.

Comment: @amI Are you saying that every object complement is also a form of raising to object or not?

Comment: I guess so (semantically) -- I welcome a counter-example.

Comment: @aml In your example, 'made' is more a control verb than a raising verb, if you know what I mean. Maybe, a more fitting example would be: _She considered him (to be) famous._ But I doubt that even pro-raising grammarians such as Postal would consider _She considered him famous_ as a raising construction.

Comment: @JK2, I found some support for your idea that "make out" is not a Raising verb. In "The s--t hit the fan", the subject has a non-literal sense.  If "make out" were a raising verb, it should be ok to change "They made out that the s--t had finally hit the fan" into *"They made the s--t out to have finally hit the fan."  But it's not ok.

Comment: But _The EU made Helsinki out as/to be a warmaker_ is grammatical, despite the metonymic capital city.

Comment: @jlawler, I don't get your Helsinki argument.  Why shouldn't Helsinki be used metonymicly as a fundamental  object of "make out"? It's not an idiom part.

Comment: Metonymic capitals was one of Postal's tests for Raising: _Helsinki seems/wants to be warlike_ vs non-metonymic _Helsinki seems/*wants to have a central fountain_.

Comment: @GregLee a. _It was easy for her to make Jerry out to be famous_. b. _Jerry was easy for her to make out to be famous_. Does b. work here?

Comment: @jlawler Could you show me any of Postal's paper or book about the metonymic capital test?

Comment: Yes, I think b. is acceptable.

Comment: @GregLee Can b. be considered additional evidence that (1) is not a raising construction but a case of 'object control'?

Comment: _Easy_, like _tough_, governs _Tough_-Movement, also called 'object control', especially by those who prefer 'subject control' to 'Equivalent Noun Phrase Deletion' or other terms. _Tough_-Movement is a minor rule, governed by a few predicates but present in a lot of idioms. In any event, not to break up the interesting discussion here, but the actual question seems more about the phrasal verb idiom _make out `NP` as/to be_, which is certainly not anything like a prototypical lexical item. That makes decisions about fine points of Raising pretty rarefied, to say the least.

Comment: @jlawler Postal seems to be saying in 'On Raising' that raised objects cannot participate in Tough Movement, whereas non-raised objects (ordinary objects) can.

Comment: Yes, given what Postal says, I do think your example b. is additional evidence that (1) is not a Raising construction.  I have no opinion about what Postal says, however.

Comment: @GregLee Thanks for confirming. I've found two Raising papers that support the Tough Movement test of Postal, and none that reject it. So far. The problem is, those two Raising papers that support the TM test show (1) as a 'raising to object' example.
(